# How can I re-calculate partial functions

Tags: c++, algorithm

I need to iterate a calculation many millions/billions of times.
For simplicity the function to solve is:

> x = (y*z/m)^n

The user specifies any 3 of the 4 variables y, z, m, and n at run time. 
The 4th variable is solved for elsewhere in code and changes each iteration.

Is there a way in c++ to pre-calculate the known variables during the initialization and only iterate the reduced form of the equation?

I'm basically looking for something like template meta programming compile time constants except at run time not compile time.

Comment: edit: 3 of 4 for clarity

Comment: Vincent - I'm not really sure how to approach this, and insight would be welcome. Currently the user re-compiles the code for every run and the constants are pre-calculated from templates.

Comment: edit: the problem is I don't have pre-existing knowledge of which variables are constant. see addition of "any 3 of 4"

Comment: Galik - How would a library implement this?

Comment: Does the function itself change at each re-compile?

Comment: Memoization (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) might be a useful approach.

Comment: Hatchet - no the function is the same, just the selection of constant variables changes. Memoization looks interesting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes:

Make an interface implemented by four different objects, one for each possible reduction. At initialisation construct the relevant implementation class depending on which constants are given, and make it a singleton object. You can then call the reduced function repeatedly.

=========

Having said that, there is no need to try this type of micro optimisation unless you have already profiled. If you are really calling a function millions of times with 3/4 parameters the same, its likely that the compiler is quite efficient at optimising it already. Always test to see if the new "clever" solution is actually faster. There are few guarantees.